# JDBC driver jar com.simba.spark.jdbc4.Driver

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, driver, simba

I'm trying to create a JDBC connection to my local spark environment.

I'm looking to "**com.simba.spark.jdbc4.Driver**" *JAR file - Version 4*.

I'm using *IBM Cognos Analytics* do create the JDBC connection which use the version 4 of JDBC.

Someone has the jar file with this specific driver?

Thanks

The last version of simba driver SimbaSparkJDBC42-2.6.19.1030 don't have de version 4 of the driver.

Comment: For more details: " You need to be using the jdbc4 driver." 
  https://community.ibm.com/community/user/businessanalytics/discussion/xqe-jdb-0012-jdbc-sparkdatabricks-connection-failure

Answer (score 0):

Only Databricks is supported using the SIMBA driver they (Databricks) distribute with their product.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/12.0.0?topic=SSEP7J_12.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_new.doc/c_ca_nf_11_2_4_databricks_support_dynamic_query.htm

Connections to Apache SPARK Server Thrift using SIMBA was discontinued.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/12.0.0?topic=new-deprecated-removed-features-in-120x